# How to rotate 3D model with 3 axis X Y Z using HelixToolkit?

Tags: c#, 3d, helix-3d-toolkit

I want to display 3d model on wpf application. Data is coming from arduino serial connection.

i can display model but i dont know how to rotate X,Y,Z axis.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform(v=vs.110).aspx

there is info about functions. i run following function to rotate object(not camera) but it doesn't move. How can i move model with only 3 variables ( x,y,z)

Models.Transform.Transform(new Point3D(x, y, z));

Answer (score 0):

The object you want to rotate should be ModelVisual3D, added to helix viewport.

Get the Matrix3D object from ModelVisual3D.Transform3D, here is a function for rotation around arbitrary axis:

```
public static Matrix3D Rotate(this Matrix3D m, Vector3D vr, double angleDeg, bool multiply = true)
    {
        var rm = new Matrix3D();
        //vr /= vr.Length;
        vr.Normalize();
        var t = angleDeg.ToRad();
        var c = Math.Cos(t);
        var s = Math.Sin(t);
        var c1 = 1 - c;
        var x = vr.X; var y = vr.Y; var z = vr.Z;
        var x2 = x * x; var y2 = y * y; var z2 = z * z;
        var xy = x * y;
        var xz = x * z;
        var yz = y * z;

        //col 1
        rm.M11 = c1 * x2 + c;
        rm.M21 = c1 * xy - s * z;
        rm.M31 = c1 * xz + s * y;
        //col 2
        rm.M12 = c1 * xy + s * z;
        rm.M22 = c1 * y2 + c;
        rm.M32 = c1 * yz - s * x;
        //col 3
        rm.M13 = c1 * xz - s * y;
        rm.M23 = c1 * yz + s * x;
        rm.M33 = c1 * z2 + c;

        if (multiply) return rm * m;
        return rm;
    }
```

Then set the Transform3D = new MatrixTransform3D(matrix3D).

Hope it helps someone...